# SQLAlchemy join with explicitly defined relationship not working

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When I attempt to join to a table/object by explicitly defining the join condition, it does not attempt to join the tables.  Can someone help me see what I am missing?

Calling this method with `foreignName=sss` has no join on the SQL generated

```
def getEvents(start=None, end=None, foreignName=None):
    query = Session().query(Event)
    if foreignName != None:
        query.join(ForeignTable, Event.type_id == ForeignTable.foreignId).filter(ForeignTable.name == foreignName)
    if start != None:
        query = query.filter(Event.start_time >= start)
    if end != None:
        query = query.filter(Event.end_time <= end)
    return query.all()
```

Generated SQL:

```
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT events.type AS events_type, events.id AS events_id, events.title AS events_title, events.start_time AS events_start_time, events.end_time AS events_end_time, events.description AS events_description, events.type_id AS events_type_id, events.event_type AS events_event_type 
FROM events
```

System:

- Mac OSX Catalina
- Python 3.7.3
- SQLAlchemy latest

This looks like the same question here, however, I cannot get this to work.
[Specify join condition in SQLalchemy ORM without foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208803/specify-join-condition-in-sqlalchemy-orm-without-foreign-key)

Comment: You've just forgot to assign the new query object in the `if foreignName != None:` branch.

Comment: `query.join(..` should be `query = query.join(...`

Comment: OMG I stared at that for so long.  I feel sheepish.  Thank you